# How do I get the medal on the game selection screen for Find Mii?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-quest-find-mii-2, streetpass-quest-find-mii

In StreetPass Mii Plaza, when you complete a game, a medal is added to the game selection screen. How do I get the medal for Find Mii? I've beaten 1 and 2 multiple times before the medal update. After the medal update I haven't played Find Mii 1 anymore and I had beaten 2 a couple of times. The medal didn't appear, however.

How do I get the medal for this game on the selection screen? I have seen other people with it. Do I need to beat Find Mii 1 again, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Find Mii's medal seems to disappear if the player restarts a quest, for any reason. Therefore it means you need to complete the current quest again.